# Anyone else experiencing aws-s3 timeout problems when looking for nonexistant keys? S3Object.exist? and S3Object.request(:head, ..)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

Has anyone been having problems with aws-s3's S3Object.exists?, or S3Object.request(:head, ...) timing out when passed keys which do not exist? (I'm running aws-s3 0.6.2, ruby 1.9.2). Using S3Object.find('thenonexistantkey', bucket) raises a NoSuchKey exception as expected. Is this an issue on amazon's side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aws-s3 gem does not set the timeout to reasonable values

You can do it by monkeypatching its `create_connection` method

Create a file `config/initializers/aws_s3_connection_monkey_patch.rb`:

```
# Sets the timeouts to appropriate values for S3
module AWS
  module S3
    class Connection #:nodoc:
      private
      def create_connection_with_timeout_settings
        http = create_connection_without_timeout_settings
        http.open_timeout = 1
        http.read_timeout = 5
        http
      end
      alias_method_chain :create_connection, :timeout_settings
    end
  end
end
```